# Extract groups matched regex to array in scala

Tags: arrays, regex, scala, extract, regex-group

I got this problem. I have a

```
val line:String = "PE018201804527901"
```

that matches  with this

```
regex : (.{2})(.{4})(.{9})(.{2})
```

I need to extract each group from the regex to an Array.

The result would be:

```
Array["PE", "0182","018045279","01"]
```

I try to do this regex:

```
val regex =  """(.{2})(.{4})(.{9})(.{2})""".r
val x= regex.findAllIn(line).toArray
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 8):

```
regex.findAllIn(line).subgroups.toArray
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that `findAllIn` does not automatically anchor the regex pattern, and will find a match inside a much longer string. If you need to only allow matches inside 17 char strings, you can use a *match* block like this:

```
val line = "PE018201804527901"
val regex =  """(.{2})(.{4})(.{9})(.{2})""".r
val results = line match {
  case regex(g1, g2, g3, g4) => Array(g1, g2, g3, g4)
  case _ => Array[String]()
}
// Demo printing
results.foreach { m =>
  println(m)
} 
// PE
// 0182
// 018045279
// 01
```

See a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/skOdm9).

It also handles no match scenario well initializing an empty string array.

If you need to get all matches and all groups, then you will need to grab the groups into a list and then add the list to a list buffer (`scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`):

```
val line = "PE018201804527901%E018201804527901"
val regex =  """(.{2})(.{4})(.{9})(.{2})""".r
val results = ListBuffer[List[String]]()

val mi = regex.findAllIn(line)
while (mi.hasNext) {
  val d = mi.next
  results += List(mi.group(1), mi.group(2), mi.group(3), mi.group(4))
}
// Demo printing
results.foreach { m =>
  println("------")
  println(m)
  m.foreach { l => println(l) }
}
```

Results:

```
------
List(PE, 0182, 018045279, 01)
PE
0182
018045279
01
------
List(%E, 0182, 018045279, 01)
%E
0182
018045279
01
```

See [this Scala demo](https://ideone.com/UU2TSC)

Comment: Is there no more succinct way than `regex(g1, g2, g3, g4) => Array(g1, g2, g3, g4)`?

Comment: @Narfanator No if you want to do it with regex pattern matching.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution @sheunis was very helpful, finally I resolved it with this method:

```
def extractFromRegex (regex: Regex, line:String): Array[String] = {
   val list =  ListBuffer[String]()
   for(m <- regex.findAllIn(line).matchData;
      e <- m.subgroups)
   list+=e
list.toArray
```

}

Because your solution with this code:

```
val line:String = """PE0182"""
val regex ="""(.{2})(.{4})""".r  
val t = regex.findAllIn(line).subgroups.toArray
```

Shows the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:372)
at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator.start(Regex.scala:696)
at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchData$class.group(Regex.scala:549)
at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator.group(Regex.scala:671)
at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchData$$anonfun$subgroups$1.apply(Regex.scala:553)
at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchData$$anonfun$subgroups$1.apply(Regex.scala:553)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchData$class.subgroups(Regex.scala:553)
at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator.subgroups(Regex.scala:671)
```

Comment: or in more functional syntax: 
val list = regex.findAllIn(line).matchData.flatMap(_.subgroups)